# saving a movie in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I used the following code and did not succeed to save the movie
Please tell me where am I wrong:

On top I used,

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import Foundation

class RecordingViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```

The code itself is activated from a button,

```
//Recording a video
    @IBAction func recordANewVideoMessage(sender: UIButton) {

        //Initiate camera
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera)
    {

        picker.sourceType = .Camera

        if let availableTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.Camera) {


            if (availableTypes as NSArray).containsObject(kUTTypeMovie) {

                /* Set up the camera defaults, movie. no editing, 3 minutes max - consider presenting time during recording, medium quality */
                picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]
                picker.allowsEditing = false
                picker.videoMaximumDuration = 180 // Perhaps reduce 180 to 120
                picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeMedium
                presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil) // presents the camera for the user


            }
        }
    }



//In case the user cancels the movie
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(UIImagePickerController) {

        presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {


    let uniqueVideoName = "/temporaryVideoName" //will be altered when we have something unique for the user

    var video = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

    let urlVideo = video.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(uniqueVideoName)"+".mpeg4").absoluteString


    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(urlVideo))
        {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(urlVideo, nil, nil, nil)
        }

        presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }

}
```

Comment: Instead of putting "nil" 3 times in `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum()`, what about using its parameter to get more info?

Comment: In the documentation: "The use of the completionTarget, completionSelector, and contextInfo parameters is optional and necessary only if you want to be notified asynchronously when the function finishes writing the movie to the user’s Camera Roll or Saved Photos album"

Comment: Indeed. But since it has a parameter error, your answer maybe in it.

Comment: Could not find the error

Comment: Quick question: Does your code calls `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum()`?

Comment: Yes (towards the end of the code)

Comment: I found out that you should use:             UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(video.path!, nil, nil, nil)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to save a video to the camera roll in swift:

```
import Photos

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if let referenceURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceURL], options: nil)
        if let phAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(phAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
                if let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: asset.URL)

                    // write the video to the temp directory
                    let videoPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "tmpMovie.MOV"
                    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
                    videoData?.writeToURL(videoURL, atomically: true)

                    let assetLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
                    assetLibrary.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL, completionBlock: { (url, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            print("saved")
                        }
                        else {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```